# Server sends back its own IP instead of the Proxy's IP

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, load-balancing

I'm currently trying to add a new dedicated application server.  I have a Load Balancer, that dispatch the traffic :

> LB -- apache2.conf

```
<Location />
ProxyPass balancer://my-cluster/
</Location>

<Proxy balancer://my-cluster/>
BalancerMember http://APP.SERVER.1.IP:80/
BalancerMember http://APP.SERVER.2.IP:80/
</Proxy>
```

I have a DNS that points to this load balancer.
But when I try to reach `http://www.my-domain.com/foo`, the reponse comes from `http://APP.SERVER.2.IP/foo` instead of `http://www.my-domain.com/foo`.

It is a problem becauses it causes my application to crash (it is a mobile app).

What did I missed ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `ProxyPassReverse` directive :

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass balancer://my-cluster/
  ProxyPassReverse balancer://my-cluster/
</Location>
```

> This directive lets Apache adjust the URL in the Location,
>   Content-Location and URI headers on HTTP redirect responses.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ProxyPassReverse http://www.my-domain.com/` ?

Comment: No, this directive will do it for you. Cf : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Comment: Thanks. I still have a problem : it looks like my POST request are converted to GET request when they arrive on one of my app servers. Do you have any idea what is causing this ?

Comment: Are you sure ? no idea...my POST still remains POST on app server side. If you are talking about a form, make sure its method is POST and not GET.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass balancer://my-cluster/
  ProxyPassReverse balancer://my-cluster/
</Location>
```